Kalman Filter Issue: Gyroscope Measures Delta Rotation but AoA is Absolute Angle
I'm working on a project where I'm combining gyroscope data (which measures delta rotation) with AoA (Angle of Arrival) measurements (absolute angles in degrees) using a Kalman filter. The goal is to estimate the absolute orientation of an object.
However, the results of the filter seem to diverge or behave unexpectedly, and I suspect the issue lies in the fundamental difference between the two measurement types:
Gyroscope: Measures rotational velocity (delta change over time).
AoA: Provides an absolute angle measurement (e.g., 20 degrees).
Here is the Kalman filter implementation I'm using:
def predict(posterior, angular_velocity, delta_t):
    x, P = posterior            # mean and variance of posterior
    dx, Q = angular_velocity    # mean and variance of angular velocity
    x = x + (dx * delta_t)
    P = P + Q * delta_t**2
    return (x, P)

def update(prior, measurement):
    x, P = prior         # mean and variance of prior
    z, R = measurement   # mean and variance of measurement
    
    y = z - x            # residual
    K = P / (P + R)      # Kalman gain
    x = x + K * y        # posterior mean
    P = (1 - K) * P      # posterior variance
    return (x, P)

# Standard deviations (adjust if needed)
gyroscope_std = 0.013   # Estimated 0.013 dps
aoa_std = 10.27         # Estimated 10.27 deg

# Initial state from the first measurement
start = 0
initial_angle = df.loc[start, 'theta_deg']
x = (initial_angle, aoa_std**2)  # (mean, variance)

predictions = []
timestamp = df.loc[0, 'timestamp']

for i, row in df[start:].iterrows():
    if i == 0:
        # Initial prediction is just the initial state
        predictions.append(x[0])
        continue
    
    delta_t = row['timestamp'] - timestamp
    timestamp = row['timestamp']
    angular_velocity = row['gyroscope_dps']
    aoa = row['theta_deg']
    
    # Use the gyroscope reading as the process model input
    gyro_reading = (angular_velocity, gyroscope_std**2)
    prior = predict(x, gyro_reading, delta_t)
    
    # Update with the AoA measurement
    x = update(prior, (aoa, aoa_std**2))
    
    predictions.append(x[0])



There are a few things, but first, your state (x) is the rotation, right? Is that in degrees? What are the units of delta-angle? Typically this is in degrees, and I am curious why you are multiplying it by time (delta_t).

It's the angular velocity; you need to estimate the angle

Gyros can output either: angular rate (rad/s or deg/s) or delta-rotation (rad or deg). Your statement "which measures delta rotation" means the gyros are outputting delta-rotation, which has the units of rad or deg. Depending on that, your x = x + (dx * delta_t) expression may or may not be correct.
